# Need to create a procedure to get the info of all the table that has the column name which is entered in the parameter of the procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a procedure where if user enters the column name, it should display names of all the table that has the column name and all the details of that table like primary key, foreign keys, etc.

I tried the code shown here, but I get an error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@columnName"

I am confused about this error.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GetColumnDetails 
    (@columnName NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    -- Procedure body
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sql = N'';

    SELECT @sql = @sql +
    N'SELECT 
        COLUMN_NAME = ''' + @columnName + ''',
        TABLE_NAME = t.name,
        DATA_TYPE = c.name,
        IS_NULLABLE = CASE
            WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ''Yes''
            ELSE ''No''
        END,
        IS_PRIMARY_KEY = CASE
            WHEN ic.column_id IS NOT NULL THEN ''Yes''
            ELSE ''No''
        END
    FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id
        AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
        AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE c.name = @columnName
    UNION
    '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @columnName;

    IF @sql <> N'' BEGIN
        SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - LEN('UNION'));
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    END
END;
GO

EXEC GetColumnDetails 'order_id';
```

Comment: You're not passing the variable to the dynamic SQL. Also, you should be using `sysname` as the data type of `@ColumnName` instead of `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: Unless you specifically need cross-platform compatability you should be using the specific sql-server `sys` schema metadata - there are bucketloads of examples out there.

Comment: FYI, using the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come to think about it,  there really is no need for dynamic SQL here at all:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GetColumnDetails 
    (@columnName sysname) 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
        COLUMN_NAME = @columnName,
        TABLE_NAME = t.name,
        DATA_TYPE = c.name,
        IS_NULLABLE = IIF(c.is_nullable = 1, 'Yes', 'No'),
        IS_PRIMARY_KEY = IIF(i.is_primary_key = 1, 'Yes', 'No')
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id
    AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
    AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE c.name = @columnName
END
```

Comment: This is probably not your fault, but the IS_PRIMARY_KEY is not correct. You probably need to add: `AND i.is_primary_key = 1` in your sys.indexes join.

Comment: @siggemannen Correct, I've simply copied the dynamic SQL from the question itself. Fixed, thank you!